Extension topology
I am reading a paper by Goldman and Sah on extension topology, but I am uncertain about the meaning of the sentences. Paraphrasing the paper:

Let $X$ be an abelian group and $M$ be a subgroup. Suppose that $M$
has been topologized so as to be a topological group. We may then use
the topology of $M$ to define a topology in $X$ by taking as a basis
for the neighborhoods of $0$ in $X$ the neighborhoods of $0$ in $M$.
That this in fact does define a topology and that $X$ is then a
topological group is trivial to verify. We shall call this the
extension to $X$ of the topology of $M$.
Note that the topology induced in $M$ by this extension is the one
previously given in $M$. We also note that if $X$ is a topological
abelian group and $M$ is a subgroup of $X$, then the extension to $X$
of the topology induced in $M$ by the given one of $X$ coincides with
the original topology of $X$ if, and only if, $M$ is an open subgroup.

If $M$ is a subgroup of abelian group $X$ and $(M,\tau)$ has been topologized such that $(M,\tau)$ is a topological group. Let $\mathcal{B}^{0}$ be a basis of the neighbourhoods of $0$ in $M$. We construct a topology on $X$ by taking as a basis of the neighbourhoods of $0$ in $X$ is $\mathcal{B1}^{0}$ equal to $\mathcal{B}^{0}$. So, the topology on $X$ is $\tau'=\{A\subseteq X\mid \forall x\in A, \exists B\in \mathcal{B}^{0}, \text{ such that } x+B\subseteq A\}$ and $(X,\tau')$ be a topological group. Is my understanding correct? thank you.

Yes, that is correct. I assume that $\tau'$ here is not basis of open neighborhoods but just neighborhoods?

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

If $\mathcal{B}^{0}$ is not a basis of neighbourhoods of zero in $M$ but just  neighbourhoods of $0$ on $M$, then $\mathcal{B}'^{0}$ can not satisfy the characterizations on a neighbourhoods basis needed to construct a topology on $X$ such that $\mathcal{B}={B+x\mid B\in \mathcal{B}^{0}}$ is a neighbourhoods basis of $x\in X$. Am I right? @Haran

Yes, that's right. A good sanity check to make sure you are comfortable with the definition in the paper would be for you to verify the statement about when taking a topological abelian group $X$, going to the subspace topology on $M$, and then extending back to $X$ yields the original topology.

So, I have to prove that the subspace topology on $M$, $\tau^{M}={M\cap A\mid A\in \tau'}$, is equal to the original topology on $M$, $\tau$? @Haran

So that direction is much easier to prove (but you should convince yourself of that too). What I meant was the following remark about when taking the subspace topology and then extending back retrieves the original topology on $X$.

@Haran what you are claiming here is not true: take $M$ to be the trivial subgroup, then the extended topology will always be discrete, even if $X$ is not discrete.

@LukasHeger I am not making that claim. You might want to read the last paragraph in the blockquote :)

Oh ok, sorry for the misreading

@Haran thank you for answering my question.
